# Plain C++ Code to Invoke COM Method with parameter

Tags: c++, com

I have been able to create an instance of SharePoint.OpenDocuments.1 ActiveX Control like so:

```
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hResult; 
IDispatch *pWApp;
LPCOLESTR strPid = L"SharePoint.OpenDocuments.1";

CoInitialize(NULL);  
hResult = CLSIDFromProgID(strPid, &clsid);
if(SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    hResult = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL , IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pWApp);
```

I have some trouble invoking the "EditDocument" method with a document name. I can't figure out how to invoke or use Variants.

Any code tips?

Comment: Use the #import directive to avoid having to write late-bound code.  That's only easy in a scripting language, definitely not in C++.

Answer (score 2):

At least if I'm reading the docs correctly, you need a BSTR, which you can create with [`SysAllocString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This is very likely the issue. The difference is that SysAllocString will add a prefix length to the string, while the manual way won't (more precisely, the first two bytes will be treated as length). Even better, use the `_bstr_t` class that manages the string and calls SysFreeString when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ATL in your C++ project, you can easily create a BSTR string by using the class [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and pass it as parameter to OpenDocuments.EditDocuments

```
CComBSTR tempBstr = _T("c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt");
someObj->SomeMethodThatUsesBSTR(tempBstr);
```

If you are not using ATL, you can then use the class [bstr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from `comutil.h` the same way:

```
bstr_t tempBstr = _T("c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt");
someObj->SomeMethodThatUsesBSTR(tempBstr.GetBSTR());
```

Both classes (CComBSTR and bstr_t) are just wrappers that will call [SysAllocString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SysFreeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) internally.